# Java: is it safe to change/replace and read same int/Object with 2 threads at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading

For example there's 2 threads: one thread reads int, other thread changes int value.

Is these threads safe from memory corruption and other dangerous stuff? Will 1st thread successfully write integer to variable and the 2nd thread successfully read the variable without any problem?

Is it the same with objects? Is replacing an object reference with another object safe when another thread repeatedly reads the object reference?

EDIT: 2nd thread will only read it, it will not change the variable

Comment: No it's not. There's the `AtomicInteger` class you can use.

Comment: Reading and writing themself are never a problem. The problem comes when you have dependencies. So for example a thread reads and then writes based on that value (`i++` for example). `i++` has a read-write dependency and if you get interrupted after the read, before the write, and another thread modifies, then you get unexpected results.

Comment: @Zabuza There's no order, the most important thing to me that when it ends writing the variable and pauses, the other thread would read the last variable correctly.

Comment: Basically no. Whenever there's access to shared memory between two threads, you _need_ synchronization. Whether it be locks, atomics, memory barriers that's up to the code. But you _need_ something, otherwise you're going to get into data races, race conditions etc.

Comment: You should just show your code and explain the desired outcome. It's hard to get the exact conditions without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe in the sense that you will never encounter a half-updated `int` variable (it will either contain the old, or the new value, but not a mixture of their bytes). While JLS, chapter 17 is no entertaining reading at all, [7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.3), [8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.3), [9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.3) and [10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.3) all contain the same cryptic words (this is the best it offers in this topic, though it later suggests that the Java Memory Model ensures something "less" than this sequential consistency):

> Within a sequentially consistent execution, there is a total order over all individual actions (such as reads and writes) which is consistent with the order of the program, and each individual action is atomic and is immediately visible to every thread.

There are some "inverted" suggestions at the very end (any of them):

> 17.7. Non-Atomic Treatment of double and long
>   For the purposes of the Java programming language memory model, a single write to a non-volatile long or double value is treated as two separate writes: one to each 32-bit half. This can result in a situation where a thread sees the first 32 bits of a 64-bit value from one write, and the second 32 bits from another write.

So the two 64-bit types might not be non-atomic, though that (them being atomic too) is the preferred case (not quoted here).

And for the specific case of object references, there is no doubt at all:

> Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of whether they are implemented as 32-bit or 64-bit values.

The suggested [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) (or its source on [GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.java)) is more like a volatile integer with extra operations from the internal `sun.misc.Unsafe` class (most of the `xAndY()` methods). It results in higher performance compared to a barefoot implementation.

By the way: there is a `volatile` keyword in Java, that is what you should use when you want to see updates happening in one thread from another thread, on all platforms.

To be honest, this weird test works for me on Windows, even without `volatile`:

```
static volatile int c=0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(!Thread.interrupted())
                c=(c+1)%3;
        }
    });
    t.start();
    int some=10;
    while(some>0)
        if(c==0 && c==1 && c==2){
            System.out.println("Bingo!");
            some--;
        }
    t.interrupt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When one thread writes and another reads, there should be no problem, but if the value of the integer is important it will make a race condition. In such scenarios use: `AtomicInteger` and/or `lock` in java. These will prevent race condition

**AtomicInteger**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html

**Lock**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html